# Merge rows with a verified condition on an attribute

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this table

```
Language                     Number

English (United Kingdom)   2
English (United States)    2
English (Australia)        2
Deutsch (Deutschland)      5
Deutsch (Schweiz)          3
```

And I need to merge the rows containing the word 'English' in one row and the rows containing Deutsch in another to have finally two rows

```
Language                   sum of numbers

English                    6
Deutsch                    8
```

All I was able to find was `group by` which is not enough in this case.

I need the `group by` behavior but not on the language values but on the condition that is there is only English and Deutsch actually

Hints would be enough no need for explicit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the language from the `language` column and do a `group by`.  Assuming the language name has no spaces and is followed by a space, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(language, ' ', 1) as language, sum(number)
from thistble
group by substring_index(language, ' ', 1)
```